# Refresh cache and data Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, caching, google-play

I develop an application with Cordova for Android and IOS.
However, when publishing an update, sometimes the application has bugs due to some data being cached. The problem is solved by emptying the cache and the data of the android application.

So I am trying to find out if it is possible to force the phone to dump this data during a new update (for major update).
Whether it's a feature from Google Play, or a feature in the application code?

Thank you in advance.
Cordially.

Comment: Vincent, is this data you are saving in localStorage on the device?

Comment: I think it's probably localStorage data that can cause problems on some updates.